# How to create chart with highchart in which bar doesn't start from 0 in y axis?

Tags: highcharts

I'm working with [this](http://www.highcharts.com/stock/column-stacked-percent) chart, and the thing I'm trying to create is that for example "Apples" bar does not start from 0 on y axis. Instead of that, I want it to start from from example 25%, and to end in 75% (so that bar in chart (its height) is from 25 to 75, when you look at values in y-axis). Does anyone have an idea of how to do that? What to change?

Answer (score 3):

You can use the column range chart type. See [this official demonstration](http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.9.1/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/demo/columnrange/).

Here is a sample of your apples ([JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/43dfztu5/)):

```
$('#container').highcharts({

    chart: {
        type: 'columnrange'
    },

    xAxis: {
        categories: ['Apples']
    },

    yAxis: [{
        min: 0,
        max: 100
    }],

    series: [{
        data: [
            [25, 75],
        ]
    }]

});
```